# why is rotating a list producing the identical values?

Tags: python, slice

I am slicing a list:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
original_nums = nums

for i in range(0,len(nums)-1):
    original_nums = original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i]
    print(original_nums)
```

The output that I get is: [1,2,3] and [2,3,1].

Two questions:

1. Shouldn't I be getting three lists?- because I am doing "for i in range(0,2)" ; why am I only getting two lists as an output? Shouldn't I get one for i=0, i=1 and i=2?
2. If I change it to 'for i in range(0,len(nums)); the output is [1,2,3],[2,3,1],[1,2,3] - I agree with the first two lists, but shouldn't the third be [3,2,1]? As we are rotating by 1 to the left each time.

Comment: The second argument of `range` is exclusive. `range(0, 2)` is `[0, 1]`

Comment: `original_nums[3:]` is the empty list `[]` since the index 3 is out of bounds already as a starting index.

Comment: `original_nums = num` serves no purpose; you aren't making a *copy* of the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: The second argument of `range` is exlusive.

For your second question: It doesn't do what you expect because you change `original_nums` in every loop as you can see here:

```py
nums = [1,2,3]
original_nums = nums

for i in range(0, len(nums)):
    print("original_nums is", original_nums, ", so original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i] will result in", original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i])
    original_nums = original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i]  # here you change original_nums, so next time this will be changed
    print(original_nums)
```

prints

```
original_nums is [1, 2, 3] , so original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i] will result in [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
original_nums is [1, 2, 3] , so original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i] will result in [2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 1]
original_nums is [2, 3, 1] , so original_nums[i:] + original_nums[:i] will result in [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

As you can see in the third loop, there is the "unexpected" array `[2, 3, 1]` used for the rotation, so you get an unexpected result.

If you change it to the following:

```py
nums = [1,2,3]
for i in range(0, len(nums)):
    print(nums[i:] + nums[:i])
```

it never changes the array that is used for generating the roation and it prints

```
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that makes sense. Quick question for the second part- why is your code different to mine? I thought they do the same thing?

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully make it clearer :)